# Why is TIMEOUT= argument not recognized within SAS PROC HTTP?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to account for missing files at a specific URL. For example, running PROC HTTP to get the following Excel file https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/cps/tables/time-series/historical-poverty-thresholds/thresh17.xls runs without timing out, eventually returning a 304 code. The SAS [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n197g47i7j66x9n15xi0gaha8ov6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) clearly lists TIMEOUT= as an optional argument, but when I try to use it I get a syntax error:

> ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, AUTH_ANY, AUTH_BASIC, AUTH_NEGOTIATE, AUTH_NONE, AUTH_NTLM, CLEAR_CACHE, CLEAR_CONN_CACHE, CLEAR_COOKIES, CT, EXPECT_100_CONTINUE,
>                 FOLLOWLOC, HEADERIN, HEADEROUT, HEADEROUT_OVERWRITE, HTTP_TOKENAUTH, IN, METHOD, NOFOLLOW, NOFOLLOWLOC, NO_CONN_CACHE, NO_COOKIES, OUT, PROXYHOST, PROXYPASSWORD, PROXYPORT,
>                 PROXYUSERNAME, PROXY_AUTH_BASIC, PROXY_AUTH_NEGOTIATE, PROXY_AUTH_NONE, PROXY_AUTH_NTLM, URL, VERBOSE, WEBAUTHDOMAIN, WEBPASSWORD, WEBUSERNAME.
>   ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.

Here is my code:

```
filename resp "C:\response";
    proc http
        url="https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/cps/tables/time-series/historical-poverty-thresholds/thresh17.xls";
        method="GET"
        out=resp
        TIMEOUT=5;
    run;
```

Is there a different way to account for timeout issues within SAS?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are not running SAS version 9.4M5.

The [9.4 What's new documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=whatsnew&docsetTarget=n14c8glgh3j7hxn1b1byjs3sqnvz.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n0axrroohigwr3n105dv74hutwvp) states in 9.4M5 (September 2017)

> PROC HTTP adds a DEBUG statement, the OAUTH_BEARER= procedure option and TIMEOUT= procedure option, and response status macro variables.

Comment: Looks like you're right - my version is M4. Thanks for the help.